# create new SharePoint 2013 server and restore existing database

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, backup, restore

I am quite new to SharePoint and I have been assigned with a major task.

One of the company's site office had SharePoint 2013 on it. Over there through Central Admin, our system team guy has taken a backup (8 TB data) of SharePoint. Now I have to prepare and restore the backup.
I haven't done such activity before and thus not clear about the exact steps and sequence I need to follow to accomplish this task.

Could please share some links documents for this. 
Brief steps I understand are;

1. Prepare Sharepoint 2013 server (install pre requisite, install SharePoint)
2. Prepare web application from central admin
3. restore database backup

But not aware of how to handle service applications and their databases, also custom applications.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that move? New productive environment? Or a Test- or DEV-environment?

Comment: Hi MHeld, It a movement from Prod to Prod environment.

Comment: My recommendation is not an answer to your question, so i write it as comment: Moving a complex system with 8TB Data and custom stuff to a new productive system without any knowledge seems not the best idea. Get an experienced consultant.